# extern "C" 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have strange error when compiling open source [lib](https://github.com/robinrowe/libunistd/blob/f369b693e14ebed7b446b0c955c50625670a78ce/unistd/getopt.cpp#L16)

I using visual studio 2019
and I created a solution to the lib  `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" ../"`
but I keep getting erros when compiling :

starting with this line :

```
    CFUNC char  *optarg = "";
```

```
C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(16,24): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(16,20): message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(30,27): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(30,21): message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(38,16): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(38,12): message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(45,16): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(45,12): message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(51,16): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(51,12): message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(85,16): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(85,12): message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(94,15): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'char *'
1>C:\Dev\my\cpp\libs\libunistd-master\unistd\getopt.cpp(94,11): message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`""` is a *constant* string. You can't just assign that to a non-constant `char *`, because then it could be mutated through the pointer.

According to [the source code of libunistd](https://github.com/robinrowe/libunistd/blob/f369b693e14ebed7b446b0c955c50625670a78ce/unistd/getopt.cpp), the implementation was taken from NetBSD, but a quick check¹ [shows](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/stdlib/getopt.c?rev=1.29&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) that NetBSD doesn't initialize `optarg` at all:

```
char    *optarg;        /* argument associated with option */
```

You could follow the same approach.

You could also turn off this error by passing `/Zc:strictStrings-` (note the hyphen) to your compiler. As long as the constant string isn't written to, there should be little harm in that.

You might want to [report this as a bug](https://github.com/robinrowe/libunistd/issues) to the library author.

---

¹ Not sure I'm looking at the latest version. It's from 2014.

Answer (score 2):

It's not strange. The type of `""` (or any string literal) is `const char[]` and the type of `optarg` is `char*`. So if the assignment was allowed you would be able to modify a string literal via the pointer `optarg`. Clearly that's not desireable.

In an older version of C++, this assignment was allowed as a special case, simply because there was too much old C code that did this. But this is no longer the case.